# Computercraft program printing new line instead of updating previous line

Tags: lua, minecraft, computercraft

I increment y (the y index of the monitor) by one each time I print a line to advance the y value (basically a newline). I'm running into an issue however, when I have done `mon_1.setCursorPos(x, y+1)` it updates the previous line as it should, however when I do  `y = y+1 mon_1.setCursorPos(x, y)` it prints a new line without updating the previous line. Any suggestions?

Here's the full code

````
    --Define some colors

color_fuel = 16
color_ok = 2243
color_error = 224455
color_blank = 0
color_active = 2240

--Tables
reactors={}
max_energy={}
produced={}
percent_capacity={}

--Globals
x = 1
y = 1
i = 0

--Lamps
lamp_1 = peripheral.wrap("colorful_lamp_0")
lamp_2 = peripheral.wrap("colorful_lamp_1")
lamp_3 = peripheral.wrap("colorful_lamp_2")

--Monitors
mon_1 = peripheral.wrap("monitor_3")

--Cap banks
cap_1 = peripheral.wrap("capacitor_bank_2")

--Helper functions
function flash_fuel_lamp() 
    lamp_2.setLampColor(color_blank)
    sleep(0.01)
    lamp_2.setLampColor(color_error)
    for i = 10,1,-1 do
        lamp_1.setLampColor(color_fuel)
        sleep(1)
        lamp_1.setLampColor(color_blank)
        sleep(1)
    end
    lamp_1.setLampColor(color_fuel)
end

function clear_lamps()
    lamp_1.setLampColor(color_blank)
    lamp_2.setLampColor(color_blank)
    lamp_3.setLampColor(color_blank)
end

--Boot Sequence

--Set lamps to black and clear screen
clear_lamps()
mon_1.clear()

--Turn on the reactors and set the status light to green
for k,v in pairs(peripheral.getNames()) do
    if(string.find(v, "BigReactors")) then
        reactors[i] = peripheral.wrap(v)
        i = i + 1
    else
        --print("Other Peripheral Detected")
    end
end

for k,v in pairs(reactors) do
    v.setActive(true)
end

lamp_2.setLampColor(color_ok)
lamp_3.setLampColor(color_active)

--Main loop

for key,value in pairs(max_energy) do
        mon_1.setCursorPos(x, y)
        mon_1.write("Reactor " .. key .. " Max Energy: " .. value)
        y = y + 1
end

while true do
    --Check the fuel level
    if(redstone.getAnalogInput("bottom") == 0) then
        lamp_3.setLampColor(color_blank)
        for k,v in pairs(reactors) do
            v.setActive(false)
        end
        flash_fuel_lamp()
    end
    
    for k,v in pairs(reactors) do
        if(v.getActive() == false) then
            lamp_3.setLampColor(color_blank)
        end
        --Calculate the energies
        max_energy[k] = v.getEnergyStored()
        produced[k] = v.getEnergyProducedLastTick()
        percent_capacity[k] = (max_energy[k] / produced[k]) * 100
    end
    
    --[[max_energy = reactor.getEnergyStored()
    energy_produced = reactor.getEnergyProducedLastTick()
    percent_capacity = (max_energy / energy_produced) * 100]]

    max_energy_cap = cap_1.getMaxEnergyStored()
    energy_stored = cap_1.getEnergyStored()
    percent_capacity_cap = (energy_stored / max_energy_cap) * 100
    
    y=y+1
    mon_1.setCursorPos(x, y)
    for key,value in pairs(percent_capacity) do
        for k,v in pairs(reactors) do
            mon_1.write("Reactor " .. k .. " Percent Capacity: " .. value)
            y=y+1
            mon_1.setCursorPos(x, y)
            mon_1.write("Capacitor output per tick: " .. cap_1.getAverageOutputPerTick())
            y=y+1
            mon_1.setCursorPos(x, y)
            mon_1.write("Capacitor input per tick: " .. cap_1.getAverageInputPerTick())
            y=y+1
            mon_1.setCursorPos(x, y)
        end
    end
    sleep(0.01)
end```
````

Answer (score 0):

So I think that you might be forgetting that when you do `mon_1.setCursorPos(x, y+1)` you're not incrementing the `y` variable, you're only passing a higher value to the called function, while with `y = y+1` `mon_1.setCursorPos(x, y)` you *are* incrementing `y`.

This explains why the previous line is not being updated when incrementing `y`, since the nested for-loops at the bottom of your code use that `y` variable as well.